# serverside-rendering react app with code splitting using loadable-components

Tags: loadable-component

I recently implemented serverside-rendering react app with code splitting using loadable-components

But it seems that loadable-components itself dependent on webpack, since loadable replaces jsonp_callback with its own reporter.

So what are the alternative options that we can use when using other bundlers like rollup, esbuild?

Do we have to manually walk through the react tree to pre configure which chunk is needed on which component unless there is no specific bundler targeted library like loadable-components when implementing code splitting on serverside rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is tsconfig typeRoots unnecessary?

First, let us consult the compiler options reference:

[The documentation for](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) `typeRoots` states (emphasis mine):

> By default all visible `@types` packages are included in your compilation. Packages in `node_modules/@types` of any enclosing folder are considered visible. For example, that means packages within `./node_modules/@types/`, `../node_modules/@types/`, `../../node_modules/@types/`, and so on.

> If `typeRoots` is specified, only packages under `typeRoots` will be included.

That second line is important: if you don't set `typeRoots` then tsc defaults to looking for directories under `node_modules` containing `@types` in their directory names.

<sub>(The documentation doesn't say if it chooses `node_modules` because of the `moduleResolution` parameter though. (I suspect I'd need to dig-in `tsc`'s source-code to find out for sure).)</sub>

If you *do* set a value for `typeRoots` than that overrides tsc's `node_modules/**/@types*` lookup logic and it will then only look in the specified directories.

---

> As I know, I have to specify the path of the above file into `typeRoots` option of `tsconfig` file since `typeRoots` defaults to look into the `node_modules/@types`.

Not necessarily. You could also add your extra typings files' locations to the `paths` parameter and leave the `typeRoots` parameter blank/un-set, which means `tsc` will retain the "`node_modules/@types`-and-ancestor-walking behavior" but will see your `.d.ts` files just fine.

This scenario is mentioned in this TypeScript GitHub thread: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13581

---

So if you're asking about your specific local environment on *your* machine: and assuming that you're sticking with the normative, typical (I dare say *mainstream*) TypeScript working idioms (such as using `npm`) then **yes**: you can remove the `typeRoots` parameter because `tsc`'s (current) default behavior is to look for `node_modules` directories in the same location as your `tsconfig.json`.

(I understand that VS Code might also be pulling some strings behind-the-scenes to make `tsc` "aware" of your project files and dependencies and for its language-server process - but that shouldn't matter as you'll notice `tsc` should work identically from the command-line outside of VS Code).

---

If you're asking about the fundamental necessity of the `typeRoots` compiler option, and supposing that you're thinking *"that because practically everyone* is using `npm` and `node_modules` then why is the TypeScript team spending their time supporting unusual development configurations?"_ - well, for many very good reasons: tools shouldn't be dependent on other tools controlled by third-parties[1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots): Consider the possibility that the `npm` ecosystem and/or NodeJS software could fall out of fashion overnight and then we'd be stuck with `tsc`'s defaults still using `node_modules` when everyone is rockin' some new cool JS environment: there'd be headaches for many years to resolve the mess (not that the JS ecosystem isn't a mess as it is).

And there are many good reasons to not use `npm` and `node_modules`: people could be using TypeScript in an environment without internet access (think: secure software development, the defence industry, national secrets, etc) - those people in those situations might have a network share full of approved or known-trustworthy libraries that won't be using `node_modules`'s naming convention - in which case if those people want to use `d.ts` files they'll need to manually configure the `typeRoots` parameter for themselves.

---

[1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) I'm aware that `npm` (which is legally separate from NodeJS, btw) is maintained by *npm Inc*, which is a subsidary of Microsoft (by way of being acquired by GitHub, also a Microsoft property), so having `tsc` depend on `npm` *shouldn't* be a problem - but that's a very recent thing: Microsoft only acquired `npm` 18 months ago in March 2020 - and Microsoft could very well spin-off *npm Inc* - or run it into the ground and everyone switches to `yarn`. So regardless of the end legal owners of whatever tooling is currently popular, you don't want unnecessary dependencies like that.

Comment: @jwkoo Provided that your `d.ts` files are within a descendant subdirectory of where your `.tsconfig` file is located then TypeScript will see them. The `node_modules` search behaviour is because many projects have the `node_modules` directory located in a sibling-to-a-parent of their `.tsconfig` file where it otherwise wouldn't see them (...I think, I might be wrong)

Comment: @jwkoo Is that only in VS Code - or also from a (non-VSC) terminal/command-line session?